# Turning off "charging" sound effect on Xperia Z3 Compact

Tags: charging, audio, sony-xperia-z3

Is it possible to turn off the sound when the charger is connected? I have got the answer from Sony Support that this is a "feature".

Answer (score 1):

No. Assuming your phone is updated to Lollipop, the sound is just always on now.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [Setting Profiles Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.probeez.liteprofiles).

If you are rooted, you can get an Xposed module that can properly do that for you. And if you are really tech savvy, you can mod the `framework.jar`, but that requires some coding knowledge and could seriously damage your device.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best answer but, try to change the ROM.

I'm using Resurrection Remix, so I can disable this sound and many other things. Like RR, other custom ROMs also have this option, such as Carbon ROM, AOKP, CyanogenMod, etc.

Some links:

- [Official Resurrection Remix site](http://www.resurrectionremix.com)
- [Unofficial release for Z3C on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/z3-compact/development/rom-resurrection-remix-t3134296)

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to vibrate or silent/priority mode prior to connecting power to your device, it will vibrate or do nothing accordingly.